# C++ Char Array pointer behavior vs string Array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, implicit-conversion

C++ Rookie with first question.Using Code:Blocks 16.01 GNU GCC compiler. 
Thanks in advance. Code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    char charArr[]="Hello";
    cout<<charArr<<endl;  //outputs Hello.

    string strArr[]={"Hello", "Stack", "overflow"};
    string *pStrArr=strArr; //pointer to strArr; same as &strArr[0].
    cout<<*pStrArr<<endl; //Derreferencing pointer , outputs Hello

    char charArr1[]="Hello";
    char *pCharArr1=charArr1;  /*pointer to charArr1.(charArr cout was Hello, not H, therefore i assumed we are storing in memory Hello);*/
    cout<<*pCharArr1<<endl;  /*dereferencing, outputs H, not Hello as i expected. */

    return 0; 
}
```

Observation;
charArr outputs Hello, therefore i assumed that creating a pointer and dereferencing it should output Hello; Actual output is H, which seems inconsistent with the behavior observed on a string Array, whereas first element is both pointed and dereferenced.

Question is: 
Clearly i am failing to understand char Array. I would appreciate an explanation of the above in (as much as possible) layman terms.

PS:did use search function and talked to the Duck. Thanks for your time. 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
After all the answers I realize the actual question should be why lines 2 and 4 produce different outputs, strArr being a memory address (behaves as a pointer) while the charArr outputs the array contents.

```
string strArr[]= {"hello","world","how", "are","you"};
cout<<strArr<<endl;//outputs 0x28fedc.

char charArr[]="Hello";
cout<<charArr<<endl; // outputs hello
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem aware that `char *pCharArr1=charArr1;` makes `pCharArr1` equal to `&charArr1[0]`. Therefore, `*pCharArr1` is equivalent to `charArr1[0]` - a single character. If you print `cout << charArr1[0]`, you'll also see a single character `H`. I'm not sure why you are surprised by the behavior.

Comment: Don't use frickin' raw arrays! _"PS:did use search function and talked to the Duck. Thanks for your time. "_ Talk to your duck further!

Comment: You need a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: This is the wrong duck: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32VLnTKz0CI . If you can understand what's he's saying, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet

```
char charArr1[]="Hello";
char *pCharArr1=charArr1;  /*pointer to charArr1.(charArr cout was Hello, not H, therefore i assumed we are storing in memory Hello);*/
cout<<*pCharArr1<<endl;  /*dereferencing, outputs H, not Hello as i expected. */
```

the object `pCharArr1` has type `char *`. It points to the first character of the string `"Hello"` stored in the array `charArr1`. Dereferencing the pointer you'll get an object of the type `char` that is the character pointed to by the pointer. It is the character `'H'`.

In this code snippet

```
string strArr[]={"Hello", "Stack", "overflow"};
string *pStrArr=strArr; //pointer to strArr; same as &strArr[0].
cout<<*pStrArr<<endl; //Derreferencing pointer , outputs Hello
```

the object `pStrArr` has type `std::string *` and points to an object of the type `std::string`. Dereferencing the pointer you'll get an object of the type `std::string` that contains the character sequence `"Hello"`. So in this statement

```
cout<<*pStrArr<<endl; //Derreferencing pointer , outputs Hello
```

this sequence is outputted.

Thus in this statement

```
cout<<charArr<<endl;  //outputs Hello
```

`charArr` has type `char *` (the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element).

In this statement

```
cout<<*pCharArr1<<endl;  /*dereferencing, outputs H, not Hello as i expected. */
```

`*pCharArr1` has type `char`.

And at last in this statement

```
cout<<*pStrArr<<endl; //Derreferencing pointer , outputs Hello
```

`*pStrArr` has type `std::string`.

Take into account that for these declarations

```
char charArr1[]="Hello";
char *pCharArr1=charArr1;  /*pointer to charArr1.(charArr cout was Hello, not H, therefore i assumed we are storing in memory Hello);*/
```

the output of these statements

```
cout<<CharArr1<<endl;
```

and

```
cout<<pCharArr1<<endl;
```

will be the same and will be equal to outputting the string `"Hello"`

However for these statements

```
cout<<*CharArr1<<endl;
```

and

```
cout<<*pCharArr1<<endl;
```

only one character `'H'` will be outputted.

In the first statement as it was mentioned the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element in the expression `*CharArr1`

Comment: Makes sense Vlad & Igor,  so looking at char charArr[]="Hello";  as the equivalent char charArr[]={'H','e','l','l','o'} i am actually pointing at the FIRST char, which is 'H'...i guess what I am struggling to understand (and to formulate as an inteligible question) is why  cout<<charArr<<endl;  //outputs Hello,  if truly charArr is equivalent to  charArr[0] (which is 'H'). Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: @RookieCplusplus This declaration charArr[]="Hello";  is equivalent to the following declaration charArr[]= { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };;

Comment: @RookieCplusplus Each statement with the << operator outputs the object that specified in the right side. If the type of the object is char then a character is outputted. If the type of the object is std::string then the string stored in the object is outputted.